# Changing Text Arduino inkShield

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I have just received inkshield purchased from [Nerd Creation Labs](http://nicholasclewis.com/projects/inkshield/), I stacked inkshield on my Arduino Mega and uploaded [THIS CODE](https://github.com/NicholasCLewis/InkShield/blob/master/ArduinoLibraries/InkShieldMega/examples/SerialTextInkShieldMega/SerialTextInkShieldMega.pde) provided by the creator of inkshield,and it works pretty well. 
I can print text ;)

Questions :

1: The code given above can only print text in a single Font. Can i add multiple Fonts in a single code.?

2: How can i change the Font to something like Times New Roman, Arial,calibri or more stylish Fonts like snell RoundHand and Zapfino.?

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The fonts are the little bitmaps starting at line 50. Each 16 bit value is 1 column of the letter to be printed. There are 10 columns of pixels per character (the `rowsPerChar` value). The least significant bit is the bottom row.

So to change the font all you need to do is change those bitmaps.

Comment: Is there any software or online tool  to create such bitmaps?

Answer (score 0):

> 1: The code given above can only print text in a single Font. Can i add multiple Fonts in a single code.?

Sure you can.

> 2: How can i change the Font to something like Times New Roman, Arial,calibri or more stylish Fonts like snell RoundHand and Zapfino.?

The top 700-odd lines of the code are the font. You just need to find a way of creating the same kind of data from your own chosen font.